# Объединить метки [мойсклад-api] и [moysklad-pos-api]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Заметил в последнее время стали часто задавать вопросы по api МойСклад.

Было две метки: [мойсклад-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4-api) и [moysklad-pos-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moysklad-pos-api). Потом [moysklad-pos-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moysklad-pos-api) у всех вопросов кто-то удалили. И вот теперь опять вопросы по этой метки начали задавать.

Давайте объединим в пользу [мойсклад-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4-api)? Метка [moysklad-pos-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moysklad-pos-api) по сути вообще не нужна, можно оставить только [мойсклад-api](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4-api).

Comment: Кто удалил, можно посмотреть в [ревизиях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/956918/revisions) вопросов.

Comment: Что делать со связанной меткой [tag:moysklad-pos-api] посоветуете?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, вопросов пока как-то мало, да и активность по тематике ещё не высокая. Наверное, нет смылса в разных метках.